# Is this correct - confused in this riddle - where does the one rupee come from....?

Tags: arithmetic, education

I have 50 rupees, and spending like this and where does that ONE rupee come from.... am right or wrong ??????

[image: WHERE DOES THE ONE RUPEE COME FROM]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum of the balance column is meaningless. If you spend 1 rupee at a time, your balance column total will be 49+48+47+...+1=1225. What does that number mean? Nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Is 30 the Balance after you have spent 20 ruppee ? In general you cannot sum up the values of the balance and the expenses and then compare them. The expenses are the (negative) changes of the balance. Above the 30 on the RHS there should be a 50. As you can see, at the end the balance is 0. Thus all the money has been spent. The 51 doesn´t make any sense.